# How to extract two integers for a string and perform arithmetic operation?

Tags: python-3.x

I have made a code that could extract an int from a string and perform calculation in python

```
user_input = input('')
     if user_input[0:3] in ['add']:                                                                            
          print(int(user_input[4]) + int(user_input[10]))
```

The code could add only one digit number but I wanna add two 'n' digit number it goes in a lengthy way for tons of lines so I don't want to repeat the same code again and again instead I need a small block of code replacing to add two 'n' digit numbers can any one give me any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `split()` to break the input string into operation and argument components, and then perform the arithmetic operation. I am assuming that your input has this format:

```
<op> <arg1> <arg2>
```

for example,

```
add 1 2
```

If the user enters `add 100 24` then when you split it you will get this:

```
>>> user_input = input()
add 100 24
>>> user_input.split()
['add', '100', '24']
```

You can bind the items of the list returned by `split()` to variables like this:

```
>>> op, arg1, arg2 = user_input.split()
>>> op
add
>>> arg1
100
>>> arg2
24
```

In order to perform the operation we need the arguments as numeric values (I'm assuming that floats may be entered):

```
>>> arg1 = float(arg1)
>>> arg2 = float(arg2)
```

Now `arg1` and `arg2` are `100.0` and `24.0` respectively. Next step is to perform the operation. You can map strings to functions using a dictionary:

```
import operator

operations = {'add': operator.add,
              'sub': operator.sub,
              'mul': operator.mul,
              'div': operator.truediv}
```

and then perform the operation like this:

```
if op in operations:
    result = operations[op](arg1, arg2)
else:
    print('Invalid operation: {}'.format(op))
```

Now you can perform any of the above operations, e.g. `div 100 20`, `sub 10 100` etc.

This works by looking up the operation in the dictionary using the `op` as a key, and then using the corresponding value as the function to call, passing the arguments to that function.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is to add stuff, you can simply split your string along the word `add`:

```
test1 = "17 add 4"

summands = test1.split("add")
result = sum(int(s) for s in summands)
print(result)
```

In case you want to do more advanced stuff, you have to split your string a bit more carefully. In this case, regular expressions can come in handy:

```
import re

test2 = "17 add 4 divide 3"
parts = re.split(r"(add|divide)", test2)
print(parts)
```

This gives you a list of number literals and operators. It's then up to you to transform this list into a computation.

Of course you can also cheat:

```
test3 = "(17 add 4) divide 3"
print(int(eval(test3.replace("add", "+").replace("divide", "/"))))
```

This is unsafe if you have no control over your input (in this case, an attacker  might use `eval` to execute arbitrary code).

**Edited to add:**

Since I'm procrastinating, I went ahead and wrote a more complete example:

```
# Testcase
test4 = "((17 ADD 4) DIVIDE 3) MINUS 4"

# Define stuff that can appear inside an expression:
operators = ["add", "subtract", "minus", "multiply", "times", "divide"]
parens = [r"\(", r"\)"]
replacements = {
    "add": "+", "subtract": "-", "minus": "-", "multiply": "*",
    "times": "*", "divide": "/",
}    
tokens = operators + parens
baretokens = [t.replace("\\", "") for t in tokens]
delims = "({0})".format("|".join(tokens))

# Split the testcase in its parts
parts = re.split(delims, test4.lower())
print(parts)

# Replace operators with their Python counterparts:
result = ""
for p in parts:
    if p.strip().isdigit():
        result += p
    elif p in baretokens:
        if p in replacements:
            result += replacements[p]
        else:
            result += p
    elif p.strip() == "":
        pass
    else:
        raise ValueError("Malformed expression: '{0}'".format(p))
print(result)

# Do the computation using eval (should probably be safe, since
# maliscious code should be refused as malformed):
computed = int(eval(result))
print(computed)
```